# ~bash: jpm command not found on mac

Tags: node.js, firefox-addon, jpm

I already installed npm. My current version of npm is v3.10.8 .
Also I have installed firefox developer edition.

I have tried many possible ways to install jpm.
So here it is what I've done:

```
- npm install jpm --global
```

Also tried using

```
- git clone https://github.com/mozilla-jetpack/jpm.git
- cd jpm
- npm install
- npm link
```

When I tried to run jpm, it shows the following error.

```
~bash: jpm command not found
```

Comment: try with complete path

Comment: I didn't get you. What you mean by complete path.